# kotlin: spring and kapt not working together

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kapt

I created a kotlin/gradle project using spring initializr.
As stated [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), if I try to add kapt like:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.2.71"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
--> kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.41"
}
```

I get the following error as soon as I try to compile the code:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:190)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1424)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:196)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.gradle.NoArgKotlinGradleSubplugin.getNativeCompilerPluginArtifact()Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/SubpluginArtifact;
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(SubpluginEnvironment.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(SubpluginEnvironment.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$2.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:184)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$2.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.RunOnceAfterEvaluated.execute(RunOnceAfterEvaluated.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.RunOnceAfterEvaluated.onEvaluated(RunOnceAfterEvaluated.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.RunOnceAfterEvaluatedKt$runOnceAfterEvaluated$1.execute(RunOnceAfterEvaluated.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.RunOnceAfterEvaluatedKt$runOnceAfterEvaluated$1.execute(RunOnceAfterEvaluated.kt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by ugrading *jvm* plugin to the same version as *kapt*.
In the end I updated all the plugins to the latest version.